# Problem mocking events attached to abstract class through constructor of other object

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, rhino-mocks

i have an abstract class and im trying to mock out events being attached to it using Rhino Mocks. Here a bit of the abstract class

```
public abstract class Download
{

   public virtual event EventHandler<DownloadProgressEventArgs> DownloadProgress_Changed;

   protected virtual void OnDownloadProgressChanged(DownloadProgressEventargs e)
   {
      if(DownloadProgress_Changed != null)
      {
          DownloadProgress_Changed(this, e);
      }

   }

   // abstract method declarations etc
}
```

ive marked the event as virtual so that it can be mocked.

In my app a Download is passed into the constructor of a DownloadEntity, within the constructore the download has its events hooked up, as follows

```
public class DownloadEntity
{
    private Download _download;

    public DownloadEntity(Download download)
    {
        _download = download;
        _download.DownloadProgressChanged += new EventHandler<DownloadProgressEventArgs>(download_DownloadProgressChanged);

    }

    public virtual void download_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressEventArgs e)
    {
    // stuff done here
    }

// other code and stuff in the class
```

}

so, this is pretty straightforwards, i want to Mock out the Download and using a DownloadEntity Verify that the event is attached, for this i have used the fluent Rhino Mocks Syntax as follows

```
    [Test]
    public void DownloadAttachesEventsWhenCreated()
    {
        MockRepository mocks = new MockRepository();
        Download dl = mocks.DynamicMock<Download>();
        DownloadEntity dle;
        With.Mocks(mocks).Expecting(delegate
        {
            dl.DownloadProgressChanged += new EventHandler<DownloadProgressEventArgs>(DummyHandler);
        })
        .Verify(delegate
        {
            // verify it is called by creating a new DownloadEntity and injecting the mock
            dle = new DownloadEntity(dl);
        });

    }

    void DummyHandler(object sender, DownloadProgressEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

i get an expected = #1 actual #0 even though when i walk through the code i can see that the handler is attached to Mocked Download. This has got me really stuck and i cant help but think im missing something really obvious here.

Thanks!

Comment: i have just got this to work by doing the following 

in the Test above i changed the code to say
    dl.DownloadProgressChanged += null;
    LastCall.Constraints(Is.NotNull());

why on earth does it work now???

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Rhino Mocks 3.5 and this is all I have to do to test your functionality of the event binding properly.

```
[Test]
public void Download_attaches_events_when_created()
{
    // Arrange
    var download = MockRepository.GenerateMock<Download>();

    // Act
    var downloadEntity = new DownloadEntity(download);

    // Assert
    download.AssertWasCalled(x => x.DownloadProgress_Changed += Arg<EventHandler<DownloadProgressEventArgs>>.Is.Anything);
}
```

If you're not using 3.5 or higher, and you can upgrade, I'd consider it to make your tests simpler.

Comment: hi chris, thanks for the answer, im using rhino 3.6 so am familiar with the AAA mechanism and your solution, im more confused why my solution doesnt work using the new fluent mocking, as my comment says, if i add a constraint it works properly, i was just hoping someone could explain why it needs the constraint and why the original didnt work